# In Eclipse, how do I make a .pdf file open with the System Editor by default?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My Eclipse plugin produces .pdf files for my users in the Project Explorer in the projects that my plugin creates.  Today, a tester noticed that on his install, when he double clicks this .pdf file in his project explorer, he gets the OLE exception dialog...

[image: OLE Exception dialog from Eclipse]

What I want to do is make so that when my plugin is installed in Eclipse, it modifies the preferences to assign the .pdf file association to the system's pdf viewer.

I realize that this might be a bad idea, since I can't assume that a user has a PDF viewer installed on his/her PC.

I noticed that when I right click the .pdf file in the project explorer, that I get a choice to "Open With" various options like "Default Editor" and "System Editor".  I'd like my plugin to make the default action be Open With -> System Editor.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look like it is possible to change or add a file association without using internal classes.

You can get the existing file associations with:

```java
IEditorRegistry editorRegistry = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getEditorRegistry();

IFileEditorMapping [] mappings = editorRegistry.getFileEditorMappings();
```

but updating the list requires using the `EditorRegistry` implementation of `IEditorRegistry` and this is an internal class. The implementation of `IFileEditorMapping` is also internal.

Update:

The `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point does have a `command` attribute for running an external program and a `launcher` attribute for running a program via a `IEditorLauncher` class. You might be able to use one of those.

Comment: Thanks greg-499.  I was afraid this was going to be the case.  I've found that on some user's machines, the file association mapping to a .pdf reader program is already done, while on others, it is not.  Do you have any idea what would cause this intermittent behavior?

Comment: It is rather hard to follow everything the editor registry does! I do notice the editors extension point has some things that might be useable - answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

Try Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations.

Add *.pdf if it is not there. Highlight it and then add an associated editor. Select the External programs radio and then Adobe Acrobat Document or another reader program.

Comment: Thanks Steve, but I'm looking for a way to do this programmatically, not manually.